Having a hard time using Microsoft Excel IF function
I have been working on a simple tracking database, and I'm having a hard time using the IF function (or if this is even the right function to use for my problem). I want to create an ID number for the data points I have observed. This means that any cell that has "Yes" in the column Observation gets an ID number, and those that have "None" will be left as is. It should look like this:
Ideal table

However, my data looks like this:
My current table

I tried =IF(H14="Yes", E13 + 1, ""), but I did not like that I have a reference cell which has the value 0 in it because an extra column might affect my analysis. Aside from that, my formula generally doesn't work because the reference cell in the 2nd argument just messes up. For example, the formula =IF(H14="Yes", E13 + 1, "") works, but the formula =IF(H16="Yes", E15 + 1, "") doesn't because the cell E15 is an invalid reference cell.

Try using MAX() function:


=IF(D2="Yes",MAX(A$1:A1)+1,"")


